# Korselt's Criterion Proof Doubt

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading [this](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/carmichaelkorselt.pdf) paper, which details the proof of Korselt's Criterion. I have a doubt regarding part ii) of the proof. Namely, when we attempt to show that for all primes $p$ that divide $n$ (which is a Carmichael number, and is consequently square-free), $p-1|n-1.$ Here is what my doubt is:

Since $n$ is square-free, then $p$ and $n/p$ are coprime. Choose a $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\text{ord}_n (b) = p-1.$ Then by CRT, there exists and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a \equiv b \pmod{p}$ and $a \equiv 1 \pmod{n /p}$ and there is a solution for it modulo $n$. Therefore, $(n,a) = 1 \implies a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}.$ However, when Conrad "reduces" this to the form $b^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p},$ I'm entirely lost. Could someone please explain why this is true? I'm not sure if I'm missing some fundamental fact about modulus or if he's using some lemma I'm unfamiliar with. I would greatly appreciate some assistance.

All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since $p \mid n$ and $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ we have also $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and since $a \equiv b \pmod p$ we therefore have $b^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.